# Star rating system in css

Tags: html, css

I Was following a ratings tutorial and only modified the code a little. However when trying to incorporate ten stars (commented out in the code provided) rather than just five, The code no longer works as expected. The code is suppose the reverse the labels so that they displayed in order from **1 to 10**. Instead it is displayed in the following order **10 9 8 7 6 1 2 3 4 5**

```css
.star-rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.star-rating input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.star-rating label {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

.star-rating label:hover,
.star-rating label:hover~label,
.star-rating input[type=radio]:checked~label {
  color: #f2b600
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="star-rating">
    <!-- <input id="star-10" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-10">
<label for="star-10" title="10 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    <input id="star-9" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-9">
    <label for="star-9" title="9 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    <input id="star-8" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-8">
    <label for="star-8" title="8 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    <input id="star-7" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-7">
    <label for="star-7" title="7 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    <input id="star-6" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-6">
    <label for="star-6" title="6 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i> -->
    <input id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-5">
    <label for="star-5" title="5 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-4">
    <label for="star-4" title="4 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-3">
    <label for="star-3" title="3 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-2">
    <label for="star-2" title="2 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-1">
    <label for="star-1" title="1 star">
        <i class=" active fa fa-star "></i>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `</label>`

```css
.star-rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.star-rating input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.star-rating label {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

.star-rating label:hover,
.star-rating label:hover~label,
.star-rating input[type=radio]:checked~label {
  color: #f2b600
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="star-rating">
    <input id="star-10" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-10">
  <label for="star-10" title="10 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
        </label>
    <input id="star-9" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-9">
    <label for="star-9" title="9 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
        </label>
    <input id="star-8" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-8">
    <label for="star-8" title="8 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
        </label>
    <input id="star-7" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-7">
    <label for="star-7" title="7 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
        </label>
    <input id="star-6" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-6">
    <label for="star-6" title="6 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
        </label>
    <input id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-5">
    <label for="star-5" title="5 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-4">
    <label for="star-4" title="4 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-3">
    <label for="star-3" title="3 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-2">
    <label for="star-2" title="2 stars">
        <i class="active fa fa-star" ></i>
    </label>
    <input id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-1">
    <label for="star-1" title="1 star">
        <i class=" active fa fa-star "></i>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: :) thanks man I have been sitting here Wondering what's wrong

Comment: That's a typo, and we aren't suppose to answer such question. There is a built-in "vote/flag as typo", and it is there for a reason. Questions and answers like these are useless to other users, and SO is not for personal debugging.

Comment: you are getting used to the site now. I am sure you know that typo issue need to be closed and not answered.

Comment: ok. I voted to close